# for each loop with counter

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript, hta

I have a `For Each` loop in VBScript that iterates through files and returns results.

The code is:

```vb
Sub IterateSearch(FolderPath)
  On Error Resume Next
  Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)

  Set Fls = fldr.files
  For Each thing in Fls
    sFSpec = FSO.GetAbsolutePathName(thing)
    objMSXML.async = True
    objMSXML.load sFSpec
    If 0 = objMSXML.parseError Then
      Dim sXPath : sXPath = "//*[local-name()='namespace']/*[local-name()='querySubject']/*[local-name()='queryItem'][contains(., '"& searchTerm &"')]/ancestor-or-self::*/*[local-name()='name' and @locale='en']"

      Dim querySubject : Set querySubject = objMSXML.selectSingleNode(sXPath)
      path.innerHtml = path.innerHtml & thing.path &"<br>"
      If querySubject Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox sXPath, "failed"
      Else
        For Each node In objMSXML.selectNodes(sXPath)
          xmldoc.innerHtml = xmldoc.innerHtml & node.text & " " & "<br>" 
'         ObjOutFile.WriteLine Linenum & "  " & thing.path
        Next
'       xmldoc.innerHtml = xmldoc.innerHtml & "<br><br>"
      End If
    Else
      MsgBox objMSXML.parseError.reason
    End If
  Next

  Set fldrs = fldr.subfolders
  For Each thing in fldrs
    IterateSearch thing.path
  Next
End Sub
```

In case of multiple results it prints as:

```
> - File Path 1
> - File Path 2
> - File Paht 3

 - result set 1
 - result set 2
 - result set 3
```

I want to implement it in such a way that result should be printed like:

```
>   1. File Path 1
 - Result Set 1
>   2. File Path 2
 - Result Set 2
>   3. File Paht 3
 - Result Set 3
```

I think I need to adjust loop and implement counter to print iteration number. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the information in two different places (`path.innerHtml` and `xmldoc.innerHtml`). If you want them displayed in the order they're processed you need to create and append new elements to your HTML body, e.g. like this:

```vb
Set p = document.createElement("p")
p.innerText = thing.Path
document.body.appendChild p

Set ul = document.CreateElement("ul")
For Each node In objMSXML.selectNodes(sXPath)
  Set li = document.createElement("li")
  li.innerText = node.text
  ul.appendChild li
Next
document.body.appendChild ul
```